# I keep getting 'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'' not sure how to correct

Tags: python

I have been working through a book called How to Automate the boring stuff Python tutorial book and I have come across an example that does not seem to run.

Here is my code:

```
while True:
print 'Enter your age:'
age = input()
if age.isdecimal():
    break
print 'Please enter a number for your age.'
while True:
print 'Select a new password (letters and numbers only):'
password = input()
if password.isalnum():
    break
print 'Passwords can only have letters and numbers.'
```

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: You're using Python 2.x, switch to 3.x or try `raw_input`.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off. Also the book uses Python 3.5, where print is followed by () with the code inside.

```
while True:
    print('Enter your age:')
    age = input()
    if age.isdecimal():
        break
    print('Please enter a number for your age.')

while True:
    print('Select a new password (letters and numbers only):')
    password = input()
    if password.isalnum():
        break
    print('Passwords can only have letters and numbers.')
```